# CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT with discrete values with explicit column names

Tags: sql

I want to execute this statement

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 AS SELECT 1, "abc", 123456789.12 UNION SELECT 2, "def", 25090003;
```

on an SQL database. However column names of the resulting table are 1, "abc", and 123456789.12. Is there a way to give the columns explicit names, e.g. like col1, col2, and col3?

I know, I could make it two statements, first a create table with explicit column names and then an INSERT INTO ... SELECT, but I wonder if theres a way to make it a single statement.

Comment: Sorry, copied the statement from my C++ source code. I edited the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give the selected columns alias names as desired:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 AS SELECT 1 AS COLUMN1, \"abc\" AS COLUMN2, 123456789.12 AS COLUMN3 UNION SELECT 2, \"def\", 25090003;
```

Comment: It seems I have to put the ASs in all SELECTs instead of just the first one. If I don't the columns are named like the values in the second SELECT. I'm executing this on SQLite, so I'm not sure if this is true for other database systems.

Comment: It varies. On oracle it is enough to do it on the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as` clause for columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 AS
    SELECT 1           as col1,
    \"abc\"            as col2,
    :
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to give the columns in your `SELECT` *aliases* using the `AS` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 AS 
SELECT 1 AS col1, \"abc\" AS col2, 123456789.12 AS col3 
UNION SELECT 2, \"def\", 25090003;
```