# CREATE TABLE … AS SELECT with discrete values with explicit column types

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to execute this statement

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 AS SELECT 1, "abc", 123456789.12 UNION SELECT 2, "def", 25090003;
```

on an SQLite database. How can I explicitely define the resulting column types?

BTW: This is a follow-up question on: [CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT with discrete values with explicit column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398790/create-table-as-select-with-discrete-values-with-explicit-column-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), column types come from the [expression affinities](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#expraff) of the result columns in the SELECT.

Plain values like `1` or `'abc'` do not have an affinity; you have to add it with `CAST`:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab2 AS
SELECT CAST(1 AS INT) AS i,
       CAST('abc' AS TEXT) as t,
       CAST(123456789.12 AS REAL) AS r
UNION ALL SELECT 2, "def", 25090003 ...
```